# Router Won't Load View Due to Missing "controlAggregation"

Tags: sapui5

I'm currently working on a web app based on SAPUI5. At the moment, it's based on HTML pages but we have to migrate to a dynamic structure. The solution will be the *router*. I've followed tons of tutorials, tried different structures (JS / XML view) but the router always throws an error saying:

> The target intro has a control id or a parent but no 'controlAggregation' was set, so the target could not be displayed. - EventProvider `sap.m.routing.Target`

This is my current router setup:

```json
"routing": {
  "config": {
    "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
    "viewType": "XML",
    "viewPath": "xx.xxxxxxx.view",
    "controlId": "appContainer"
  },
  "routes": [
    {
      "pattern": "",
      "name": "intro",
      "target": "intro"
    }
  ],
  "targets": {
    "intro": {
      "viewName": "intro"
    }
  }
}
```

The `"controlId"` points to the `<App>` control in my `"rootView"`.

I tried with very simple view (like Text only), but the problem persists.

```xml
<mvc:View
  controllerName="xx.xxxxxxx.controller.app"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  displayBlock="true"
>
  <App id="appContainer"/>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message indicates, the router doesn't know into which aggregation  the "intro"-view  should be added. Since the control App has an aggregation named "pages" (inherited from [NavContainer](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainer.html#constructor)), include `"controlAggregation": "pages"` to the attribute `"routing"/"config"`.